# How to integrate SQL Server logs with stack-driver console for a instance created in Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to integrate google cloud stack-driver with SQL-Server (Express or Standard) created through Cloud SQL, so that the queries executed from a SQL client like management studio or sqlcmd or SQLPro will be displayed on the stack-driver console as logs. Is there any plugin which i need to install for this to be achived? Can this be achived natively without any third party tool?

Can anyone please give an idea?

Comment: Have you looked at this instruction: [Cloud SQL logging](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/logging#console)?

Comment: @FaridShumbar thank you i have looked into the stack driver console,  the query execution logs ddl,dml statements, are not displayed in the stackdriver console